# React Native Fixed Bottom Input Keyboard (Social Media Post UI)

Tags: android, ios, react-native, jsx

I am trying to create a view post ui for a social media feature of our app. We have a post (the flatlist header component), the comments (the flatlist), and a fixed bottom text input that leverages zIndex to be placed over the flatlist to post comments. The problem is I cannot for the life of me figure out how to properly use a keyboard avoiding view to somehow push this fixed input up when the keyboard is shown. Is there any way to do this or maybe a simpler approach to this ui that I'm missing? I have tried using the keyboard height and adding it to the bottom positioning of the input but its slow and definitely isn't viable.

[image]
[image]

Code:

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <View
        style={{
          ...styles.container,
          marginTop: 0,
          zIndex: 1,
        }}>
        <FlatList
          style={{minHeight: '100%'}}
          data={new Array(15)}
          renderItem={({item, index}) => <CommentRow index={index} />}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => `${index}`}
          ListHeaderComponent={renderHeader}
          contentContainerStyle={{paddingBottom: 70}}
        />
      </View>
      <View
        style={{
          position: 'absolute',
          bottom: 0,
          backgroundColor: 'white',
          width: '100%',
          zIndex: 2,
          padding: 15,
          borderTopWidth: 1,
          borderColor: '#f2f2f2',
        }}>
        <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
          <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder="Add a comment.." />
          <View style={styles.inputTextContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.inputText}>Post</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone looking to do anything like this - what I ended up doing is using an useEffect hook to monitor when "keyboardWillShow" and then created a function to animate the view above the keyboard once its about to show. A lot of the answers I had seen used "keyboardDidShow" but it makes the UI slow and really ugly. Here's the code:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    Keyboard.addListener('keyboardWillShow', _keyboardWillShow);
    Keyboard.addListener('keyboardWillHide', _keyboardWillHide);

    // cleanup function
    return () => {
      Keyboard.removeListener('keyboardWillShow', _keyboardWillShow);
      Keyboard.removeListener('keyboardWillHide', _keyboardWillHide);
    };
  }, []);



const _keyboardWillShow = (e) => {
    const keyboardHeight = e.startCoordinates.height;

    Animated.timing(topValue, {
      toValue: -keyboardHeight,
      duration: 50,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start();
  };

  const _keyboardWillHide = (e) => {
    Animated.timing(topValue, {
      toValue: 0,
      duration: 0,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start();
  };
```

Where topValue is a stateful Animated value. All you need to do after this is add the topValue variable to your animated view using transform and you're done!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a fan of keyboard avoiding view because of some bad experiences I had. However, I'll give some tips on how to achieve the same effect with React Native core Animated Library.

Since your view is elevating (Style it as an absolute view) and when the keyboard appears, you can get the height of the keyboard with Keyboard addListener's callback.

```
componentDidMount(){
    this.keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidShow', this._keyboardDidShow);
}

_keyboardDidShow(e) {
    const keyboardHeight =  e.endCoordinates.height, 
}
```

Once you get the keyboard height, you can animate the absolute view using translateY to the position that aligns with the keyboard without any gaps. This will provide an nice animation similar to that you tried to accomplish with keyboard avoiding view. I've done that in few apps as well and it works great.